# Make WTForms set field label from database model

Tags: flask, wtforms, entity-attribute-value

I have three tables: *components*, *attributes* and *attribute_values*. Each component can have many *attribute_values*. Each *attribute_value* belongs to one *attribute*. Yeah, it's the dreaded EAV pattern...

I have created these two forms:

```
class AttributeValueForm(Form):
    attribute = HiddenField()
    value = StringField('Value')

class ComponentForm(Form):
    ... non-related fields left out ...
    attribute_values = FieldList(FormField(AttributeValueForm))
```

These are the SQLAlchemy models:

```
class Component(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'components'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ... non-related columns left out ...

class AttributeValue(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'attribute_values'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = db.Column(db.String)

    attribute_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('attributes.id'))
    attribute = db.relationship('Attribute', backref='attribute_values'))

    component_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('components.id'))
    component = db.relationship('Component', backref='attribute_values'))

def Attribute(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'attributes'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(60))
```

My problem is that I would like to see the *name* of the attribute as the label of the value field (replacing 'Value'). I've been trying to wrap my head around how WTForms work internally, but I can't see any obvious way to do this.

Any hints appreciated. I could even do with a hack that just renders a custom label, if I could only get hold of the AttributeValue object while rendering the value field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so I came up with a solution, which is a bit similar to adarsh's second comment to his answer, but overriding **init** of the Form used by the FormField:

```
class AttributeValueForm(Form):
    value = StringField('Unnamed attribute')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AttributeValueForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'obj' in kwargs and kwargs['obj'] is not None:
            self.value.label.text = kwargs['obj'].attribute.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using `ModelForm` from [wtforms-alchemy](https://wtforms-alchemy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

You could the define the form with the model quite easily.

Something like:

```
class AttributeValueForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Attribute
        only = (... columns that you want to include ...)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to *edit* or *change* the attribute type/name: i would just like to change the *label* of the *value* field. I've already used QuerySelectField on Attribute.name, which works as expected.

Comment: I'm still a little confused about your question, but if I understood you correctly, you could pass the `AttributeValue` object while constructing the form and just change the label like this? `form.value.label = attribute_value_object.whatever`

Comment: Each Component may have many AttributeValues and they are populated automatically by WTForms using FieldList (see ComponentForm above). So I don't have access to the AttributeValue-instance that created each of the AttributeValueForm instances after the form has been constructed (unless there's a way to find what object was used to populate a Form after it has been constructed?). Of course I have access to all AttributeValues, but I don't know *which* of these was used to populate each *AttributeValueForm*.