# Flask WTForms Dynamic Editable Table Fields with Field Names

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

How can I get the Field Names to return as text/string?

[Highlighted "Field Names" I want returned as text, not fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsC46.png)

I am dynamically creating a list of fields and then appending values. But I can't seem to figure out a way to return the field names as plain text. The below code appends them to a field (fieldname)-- which is the only way I have been able to return them.

```
class ContractFields(FlaskForm):
    fieldname = StringField()
    fieldvalue = StringField()

class ContractForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('title')
    contractfieldlist = FieldList(FormField(ContractFields))

@app.route('/tester.html', methods=['GET','POST'])
def contractfields():
    form = ContractForm()
    for f in object:
            document_form = ContractFields()
            document_form.fieldname = f.name #need this list object to return as table text, not a field
            document_form.fieldvalue = f.value

            form.contractfieldlist.append_entry(document_form)

    return render_template('tester.html', form = form)
```

And from the template:

```html
<div>
  <form action="" method="post" name="form">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th> ListNumber </th>
          <th> Field Name </th>
          <th> Field Value </th>
        </tr>
        {% for items in form.contractfieldlist %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ items.label }}</td>
          <td>{{ items.fieldname }}</td>
          <td>{{ items.fieldvalue }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </table>
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" name="edit" value="Send"></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

My experience with Python has largely been limited ETL and data transformation so I don't understand why this was so complicated. But after way too many hours I finally found the [following solution worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378241/make-wtforms-set-field-label-from-database-model).

Specifically modifying the associated excerpt from the above post to be the following:

```
class ContractFields(FlaskForm):
        fieldname = HiddenField()
        fieldvalue = StringField()
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                super(ContractFields, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                if 'obj' in kwargs and kwargs['obj'] is not None:
                        self.fieldvalue.label.text = kwargs['obj'].fieldname
```

And the template html to:

```
      <td>{{ items.label }}</td>
      <td>{{ items.fieldvalue.label }}</td>
      <td>{{ items.fieldvalue }}</td>
```